# Real analytic function: zero set of the gradient is a subset of the zero set of the function

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry, real-analytic-structures

I had this question when reading Bierstone and Milman's famous paper "Semianalytic and subanalytic sets". In their proof of the Łojasiewicz gradient inequality (Proposition 6.8 in the paper), they used the following: for any function $g$ real analytic in a neighborhood of the origin such that $g(\mathbf{0})= \nabla g (\mathbf{0}) = 0$, there exists a small ball $K$ centered at $\mathbf{0}$ in which the zero set of the gradient $\nabla g$ is contained in the zero set of $g$. Does anyone know how to prove this statement or can provide some reference? Thanks!

Comment: But what if $\nabla g$ is not 0 or does not have isolated zero at the origin.

Comment: Id the zero set is not isolated at 0, you can integrate along it and show that the function is zero on this set, as stated.

Comment: You need something like the Weierstrass Preparation Theorem to see that the zero locus of the gradient is smooth enough to integrate along, i.e. that any two points of that locus are connected by a rectifiable path, if you work inside a small enough ball. To me, that is not immediately obvious. Then you apply Alexandre Eremenko's comment: if the gradient is normal to a set connected by rectifiable paths, then you can integrate and see that the function is constant on that set.